# No index provider 'spatial' found

Tags: spring, neo4j, spatial

I tried to create a class called Neo4jPoint with an attribute 
@Indexed(indexType=IndexType.POINT, indexName="geolocation"
String wkt;

When I run my junit test case, it encountered the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No index provider 'spatial' found. Maybe the intended provider (or one more of its dependencies) aren't on the classpath or it failed to load.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.getIndexProvider(IndexManagerImpl.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.getOrCreateNodeIndex(IndexManagerImpl.java:303)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.forNodes(IndexManagerImpl.java:289)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.forNodes(IndexManagerImpl.java:283)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.DelegatingGraphDatabase.createIndex(DelegatingGraphDatabase.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProviderImpl.createIndex(IndexProviderImpl.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProviderImpl.getIndex(IndexProviderImpl.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProviderImpl.getIndex(IndexProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getIndex(Neo4jTemplate.java:650)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.IndexCreationMappingEventListener$1.doWithPersistentProperty(IndexCreationMappingEventListener.java:51)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.IndexCreationMappingEventListener$1.doWithPersistentProperty(IndexCreationMappingEventListener.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:240)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.IndexCreationMappingEventListener.ensureEntityIndexes(IndexCreationMappingEventListener.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.IndexCreationMappingEventListener.onApplicationEvent(IndexCreationMappingEventListener.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.IndexCreationMappingEventListener.onApplicationEvent(IndexCreationMappingEventListener.java:31)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:294)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:60)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:43)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getPersistentEntity(Neo4jTemplate.java:601)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getMappingPolicy(Neo4jTemplate.java:486)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getMappingPolicy(Neo4jTemplate.java:656)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.save(AbstractGraphRepository.java:110)
    at com.isc.enabler.topology.impl.NodeRepositoryImpl.create(NodeRepositoryImpl.java:94)
    at com.isc.enabler.topology.impl.Neo4jLocationTest.testCreateLocation(Neo4jLocationTest.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am using spring-data-neo4j 2.2.2.RELEASE

What am I missing here?  I tried to follow "Good Relationships by Michael Hunger" but got lost there at spatial portion...

Many thanks in advance
David

Answer (score 1):

You must provide the `neo4j-spatial` dependency as it is not included with SDN or Neo4j.

[SDN Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#reference%3aspatial), [Neo4j Spatial at Github](https://github.com/neo4j/spatial), [Including Neo4j Spatial with Maven](https://github.com/neo4j/spatial#using-neo4j-spatial-in-your-java-project-with-maven)

Comment: Many thanks.  Solved by adding the neo4j-spatial in my pom.xml.  Another problem arises when i run my test case:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index with the same name but different config exists!  
The test case passed the first time.  Then subsequently when it's trying to deleteAll() the remote neo4j database, the above exception occurs.
Any idea?

Comment: If you are using spring-data-neo4j-rest, have you installed the neo4j-spatial server plugin?

Comment: The exception can happen if you create two indices of different types with the same name. Possibly you inadvertently do so in your code. But I think you can also get that exception if the server plugin is not installed. Please consider editing your original question with details if you think the issues are related, or 'accept' the answer and post a new question if you think the issues are distinct.